# Clean ubuntu install on preinstalled windows 8 ultrabook

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, partitioning

I've bought a new hp ultrabook (hp-b080br), it came with windows 8 preinstalled but i'm looking into install ubuntu on it.

As I've been reading through the internet, that notebook came with UEFI and there's tons of questions around installing ubuntu on dual-boot with windows 8 and UEFI.

But what i'm looking for is to remove windows 8 and have only ubuntu on my machine, but i'm afraid of removing all partitions and lead my computer usable.

So, is it ok to remove all partitions? Should I leave any (Recovery maybe?)

Here's the partition scheme according to GParted:

```
/dev/sda1 | ntfs    | WINRE    | 400mb  | hidden, diag
/dev/sda2 | fat32   |          | 260mb  | boot
/dev/sda3 | unknown |          | 128mb  | msftres
/dev/sda4 | ntfs    |  OS      | ~400gb |
/dev/sda5 | ntfs    | Recovery | 17.4gb | hidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to remove all the partitions before installing ubuntu. In fact, that's recommended if you're doing a ubuntu-only system. Make sure you have the means to install Windows 8 (your recovery discs), just in case you decide you want to go back.

You can delete the partitions using whatever tool you want (you can even use the ubuntu installation disk), and run the installer. It will build all the necessary partitions you need.

**There a few things to consider since you mentioned you have a UEFI system:**

- Install 64-bit ubuntu, as 32-bit will not recognize the EFI mode.
- Make sure you're using the latest version (UEFI support was added as of 11.10)
- You have the option of installing ubuntu in EFI mode, but it may or may not be necessary.

The best thing to do would a be a trial and error as suggested on the [UEFI documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) for ubuntu.

Comment: I agree with most of this post; however, EFI/UEFI support was added to Ubuntu a long, long time ago (I don't recall the version number, but it was literally years ago). What was added with 12.10, and later with 12.04.2, was Secure Boot support. That's a feature of only the latest EFIs, and it can be disabled if you want to install an earlier version of Ubuntu. (That said, installing an old Ubuntu is seldom a good idea.)

Comment: @RodSmith I misread their documentation, it was added 11.10. I updated my answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it existed before then, but I don't recall when it was added, and there are no clues in the [Ubuntu release notes](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/releasenotes) as far back as 8.04. The documents I've found that mention 11.10 specifically are wikis, and so are of suspect veracity, with the exception of an article that I wrote for *Linux Journal* that referred to 11.10 because it was the latest version. This detail is largely academic, though; few people should be running anything as old as Ubuntu 11.10, especially on more modern hardware.